# Adobe CQ. Processing URLs without .html

Tags: jakarta-ee, adobe, aem, dispatcher

I have these URLs:

`http://example.com/about.html`

and

`http://example.com/about`

First work fine. Second shows me 404 error. Some pages works fine, some no. It happens also on country branches.

So is here a place were I can configure it(please in details)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQ requires an extension as it can render resource in many different ways (json, xml, html, etc.) I think the best way to set such default extension is to use `mod_rewrite` in Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Default renders in CQ5 are .html, pdf and xml.
Hitting any URL you have to add extension without which cq will not know what is the format to render the page and it shows 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that CQ needs an extension to render a resource, or more precisely sling does:
[Sling Cheatsheet](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/sling_cheatsheet.html)

Though it is possible to provide URLs without an extension. This is called a [Vanity Url](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/vanity-urls.html)
So if you say, some work and some don't, check the ones that work if they have set a Vanity Url and set it to the ones that don't.

In addition to that you have to check if the dispatcher allows requests to anything below "/"
Usually you deny "/" and allow some path below like "/content". But from your example it seems this is not the case for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Day CQ Link Checker Transformer" configuration, you can strip HTML extension there, but also as others have pointed out, you will need Apache rules to allow extension-less URLs to work, since Sling still needs it.